# iOS, adding frameworks to the app, affecting performance

Tags: ios, objective-c

When building an iOS app, how relevant is it to make sure the number of native frameworks is to minimum? meaning that if I want to ad AVfoundation, ot coregraphics, I assume it would add to the memory footprint? is that assumption correct? or is it because those are apple frameworks they don't add to the memory footprint? 
what if I add third party frameworks? do those affect memory footprint or app size?

I just couldn;t find good documentation on this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are dylib they won't make your app size heavier. Of course they will consume RAM when you will use them. By the way static library (third party frameworks) will add memory footprint. Since you can only create custom static library on iOS.